# Can I add Jenkins job stages to the pipeline at runtime?

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that runs a Python code. The python file is located in a stage called "run".
Can I add more Jenkins job stages *from python code* - at runtime?

I mean, the final result would be 3 stages in Jenkins following Python code run:

- run stage
- errors stage
- summary stage

Answer (score 0):

I dont think adding stages at runtime is possible.But what is the intention of adding runtime stages so that would help in providing better suggestions?
One option could be : You can  continue executing scripts in the run stage itself and take the return status, based on the conditions you could execute remaining stages which would be static but executed on codition based on the return status of the stage.